# GO Lang packages code does not changes

Tags: go

First of all dont judge me for my noob question :) I'm still learning GO!

I have the following structure in my workspace:

```
/src/todos-app
    /main.go (package main)
    /todos
       /todo.go (package todos)
       /todoReposotitory.go (package todos)
```

The main package is using the "todos" package and when I run the command "go run main.go" everything works fine at the first time but when I change the code inside todos package the following changes are not propagated outside the todos package.

Do I have to use a special command to rebuild the package todos?

Comment: Src is in your GOPATH right?

Comment: Yes it is, if I run "go env" my GOPATH is C:\GO\src

Comment: What do you mean by not propagated ? How is your import in main.go ?

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I have found the problem. 
I had the GOPATH in the same folder where it's installed and it's not recommended.